# js and css are not applied to html as static files of nestjs backend solution on nginx server (localhost works correctly)

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, nestjs, static-content

Hello dear dev community.

I would appraciate your help with complex issue related to static content (html, css, js) and nginx configuration.

I have backend solution with nestjs framework that returns to frontend some static content (html, css, js).

When I launch it locally **localhost** works correctly.

But after deploy to server with nginx configuration I faced with issue:

**css styles and js scripts are not applied to html.**

Could you please advise what would be the possible fixes of this issue.

[image]